# How do travel sites get cheaper air fares?

Tags: fares, travel-agents, emirates, expedia

I was searching for a few flights for my parents, specifically from JFK to visit India (bucket list trip). Emirates was their airline of choice. On directly checking on Emirates.com, the shown fare was around $1000 per person; however, on searching on Expedia, the fare for the *same* flights came up to $750 per person. I ended up buying the tickets on Expedia and I was able to confirm on Emirates.com that the tickets were generated and indeed valid.

So how does this work? Does the airline allocate *x* tickets to their booking partners/travel agents and did the number of available tickets for that fare on Emirates run out while it was still available on Expedia?

Comment: Useful [reading](/questions/49412/how-do-airlines-determine-ticket-prices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain large travel agents negotiate [consolidator fares](http://www.airfarewatchdog.com/blog/3802617/all-about-consolidator-airfares/) with airlines.

The link is a few years old but I don't think there is anything significantly out of date:

> A consolidator will have a contract to sell private fares at
>   a lower price than the published fare. If there's a printed ticket,
>   only "bulk" generally appears on the receipt. They generally can't -
>   or won't - sell the ticket straight to you, but will offer it through
>   a travel agent (including an online travel agent such as Travelocity
>   or Expedia), or agencies such as the ones that advertise in Sunday
>   newspaper travel sections. The agent adds their markup - keeping the
>   margin slim so they're not out-priced by published fares - and passes
>   the remaining savings on to you. True consolidators don't buy in
>   quantity or ahead of time. Rather, they pull availability from their
>   assigned class until the airline decides to close the window.

Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_consolidator) on the same:

> An airline consolidator is a wholesaler of airline tickets. Airlines
>   use consolidators as a means to reach out to more niche target
>   audiences, and by offering discounts and fare flexibility that is
>   relevant to the target group. Consolidators work through contracts
>   with major carriers to sell at reduced prices