# How can budget OTAs offer prices that are 25% of what the airline charges?

Tags: budget, bookings, online-resources, flight-search-engines

Example https://www.momondo.de/flight-search/BOS-MAD/2021-06-26/2021-07-02/business?sort=bestflight_a

Boston <-> Madrid, business, Jun 26 to Jul 2. On Momondo.de this yields a few budget OTAs (Online Travel Agency) for as low as $603. Price on TAP Portugal (the airline) is close to $2600.  So the OTA price is less than a quarter of the airline price.

I'm aware that some OTAs can be shady or even outright scammers, but I found this fare to be bookable on some of the better ones, for example Priceline. I had good experience with Priceline before: In fact, they provided a much better Covid refund experience than, for example, Air France did.

What's also weird about this one is that it sometimes doesn't show up at all  and I have to repeat the same search. Also the cast of OTAs seems to vary and also the price seems to fluctuate a bit from search to search.

These fares do not show up on ITA Matrix. On skyscanner it does show up but only with an outfit named gate1.nl which I have never heard of.

Specific questions:

1. What can I do to determine whether this is a real deal or not?
2. Why do price, OTAs and overall availability fluctuate from search to search ?
3. How is it possible that on OTA can offer the same flight at a quarter of the price?

So if anyone has an idea what's going on here, I'd be interested to learn more.

Comment: Theres an excellent post somewhere in Travel SE which goes into huge depth on how airline ticketing and pricing works - I feel that even if it doesnt outright answer your own question, you would do well to read it.  Just have to find it now 

Comment: With airline pricing I thought the standard answer was "because they can", in this case meaning that TAP is able to get away with 4x what the OTAs are charging, and not that the OTAs are charging 25% of actual cost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do travel sites get cheaper air fares?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74598/how-do-travel-sites-get-cheaper-air-fares)

Comment: I am seeing $600 on Matrix, so possibly just a temporary data flow issue?

Comment: The question is NOT a duplicate of the one above.  These seem to be valid fares with very restricted availability - however they are available directly from TAP so they are NOT consolidator fares!

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I don't think it does. This could account for a price difference of maybe 50%-100% but not 400%. This example is a factor of 4!!

Comment: @waiwai933 Cheapest that I see  on ITA Matrix around $2000 with Azores Airlines. What is your specific search and did you look for business or economy?

Comment: Airlines sell fares through a number of channels. Some fares are sold only through certain travel agents, often corporate agents who get a rebate if they sell a certain volume. These are called corporate fares. This makes it reasonable in some circumstances to sell off unsold inventory at low prices to meet the threshold for a rebate. However the airline does not allow them to sell the inventory too publicly, since it will interfere in their own demand management. ITA only searches public fares. Availability information is cached because each look up is expensive. Caches go stale fast.

Comment: @Hilmar - Ah, my mistake, I was looking at economy. Looking at Priceline specifically for that TAP flight, their $656.45 fare is on a JUSEXI9E fare code (go through to the page where it asks for payment info, then click "Billing Conditions", then "full fare rules", then the line beginning "Base - " - or open up dev tools and watch network traffic). The fare rules from Priceline specify that this is a Consolidator Fare and contain no flight number restriction - as publicly available, the fare rules for the same fare code do not allow travel on TP 217/218 (the BOS-LIS segment), per ExpertFlyer.

Comment: I have had one such experience back in Feb 2018 when I was booking a return ticket from IAD to LHR. Had gotten that fare on Virgin Atlantic’s direct flight through Priceline’s famous express deals at USD 646 (express deals don’t reveal the airline until after the booking is made). I checked the same fare on VA website immediately after the ticket was made and the website showed the ticket upwards of USD 2000. Have wondered ever since how on earth is Priceline able to offer such low fare.

Comment: The overall lesson here is: most airline's margins are astronomical if you simply buy a straight forward ticket - they can afford to give 75% rebate and still make money.

Comment: @Moo:  Is [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49417/31165) the answer you were remembering?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yup, thats the one alright!  Thank you for finding it!

Answer (score 4):

It's showing [as $1905](https://www.momondo.com/flight-search/BOS-MAD/2021-06-26/2021-07-02/business) for me now.

I run an OTA ([Beat That Flight](https://beatthatflight.com.au/)) and play with dates/prices a lot.  Sometimes you get [error fares](https://beatthatflight.com.au/index.php/2020/07/03/error-fare-business-class-from-brisbane-to-amsterdam-from-1161-on-eva-air/) where an OTA or provider genuinely has the wrong price (They've often forgotten fuel costs or tax or conversions).  There are whole sites dedicated to finding these as they tend to not last long.

In that case, it was either an error fare, or a timing issue. Often you have to click through to the actual sales page and it'll say 'oops, that price has expired, it's now X'.

Interestingly, [Beat That Flight is showing me $2141 for that route (USD)](https://bookings.beatthatflight.com.au/flights/bos2606mad0207b1) with Lufthansa.  Every route varies!

For your other parts, my data provider also takes a cut. Somewhere along the line, either someone is taking a loss, maybe to get themselves out there, or to promote a deal (Eg $1 seats, but only 2-3 of them on a flight).  In Australia, for example, my site almost always has 1-5 dollars off Jetstar flights, and always used to show cheaper prices than TigerAir, finding them on other providers.  It's an insanely complex industry, price wise.  From [this page](https://www.travelexperts.com/Portals/0/Whitepaper/The%20Truth%20about%20Finding%20the%20Lowest%20Airfare.pdf):

"Each day an airline is constantly making changes to their fares and rules. There are millions of fare and rule changes made each day. Approximately 90% of worldwide commercial airfare is distributed through a clearinghouse in Washington, D.C. called ATPCO (Airline Tariff Publishing Company). ATPCO is owned by over 20 airlines and holds and distributes (to a select few subscribers) airfares for over 500 airlines worldwide.  "Airlines participate in ATPCO to have a common format and distribution point for their airfares.  Tickets are sold for a given airline through a variety of distribution channels including airline websites and call centers, travel agencies (leisure/business/online/offline), packaging and tour operators, airline partners, affinity group agencies (students, missionaries, alliances),and consolidators. Tickets for a given airline may be sold by thousands of different travel companies worldwide. Millions of fare and rule changes are made each day. Hundreds of thousands of fare price and rule changes flow continuously into ATPCO each day.In turn,fares are distributed at specified times later the same day to a handful of subscribers worldwide that then provide the data to reservation systems,including the airlines themselves.  Once distributed, each vendor updates databases at different intervals:2-4 hours for domestic fares, and 4-8 hours for international fares.The domestic 8 PM airfare feed is not loaded until after midnight on reservation systems.  This explains why fares may vary by website and are not always consistent across the board."